# Does Gmail API Support Codeigniter Without SMTP?

Tags: codeigniter, gmail-api

Does Gmail API Support Codeigniter?
I searched on the internet and just found the code using the SMTP server only.
I want to use Gmail API instead of SMTP. It will be really appreciated if you guys can help me with it... :)

Comment: https://github.com/shirshak007/codeigniter_email ...see if it can help

Answer (score 0):

- First you have to generate app password, login to google account -> Manage Google Account -> Security -> enable 2-step verification.
- App Passwords field will appear, click then choose other and give some name. The password will be provided

  ```
   $config['protocol'] = PROTOCOL;
   $config['smtp_host'] = "smtp.gmail.com";
   $config['smtp_user'] = "youremail@gmail.com";
   $config['smtp_pass'] = "your_app_password";
   $config['smtp_port'] = "587";
   $config['smtp_crypto'] = 'tls';
   $config['smtp_keepalive'] = TRUE; // to enable persistant smtp connection
   $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
   $config['send_multipart'] = FALSE;
   $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
   $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

   $this->email->initialize($config);
   log_message('debug', 'Email preferences initialized successfully!');

   $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

   $this->email->from("sender@gmail.com", "sender_name");
   $this->email->to("receiver@gmail.com");

   //email subject
   $this->email->subject("Test Email 2");

   //email body
   $this->email->message("This is a test email"); //you can send html email too

   if($this->email->send()) {
       log_message('debug',"Mail Sent successfully!");
   } else {
       log_message('debug','Print Debugger with body: '.$this->email->print_debugger(array('body')));
   }
  ```

This is the all you need, you can check your `sent mails` in gmail.

For reference : https://github.com/shirshak007/codeigniter_email

Comment: Thanks for your help, Is there any way that I can send emails via Gmail API instead of using SMTP? actually, my client thinks that SMTP is very slow and we can send Emails faster using Gmail API